# Sort JAVA Parent list based on inner list of dates

Tags: java, sorting, java-stream, comparator

I have a class that I want to sort based on the list of Dates within another child object in that class.

Model:

```
Student {

    String name;

    List<Action> actions;

}

Action {

    String type;
    Date lastActionDate;

}
```

So now I have List that I want sorted so that the action performing latest Students comes first.

I have tried:

```
public Date getLatestActionDate() {
        return actions.stream().map(a -> a.lastActionDate).min(Date::compareTo).get();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student o) {
        return getLatestActionDate().compareTo(o.getLatestActionDate());
    }
```

But does not help. Looking forward to awesome answers.

I expect sorted student list.

Comment: For the record: please consider adding enough "example" data and context code to have a real [mcve]. Just enough code that shows the problem, but that people can quickly download and run.

Comment: What is the output?

Comment: But first value is always the one that should not be here, rest of the results are sorted. Thus, the issue remains.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getLatestActionDate` method you've created in a `Comparator` and sort the list as:

```
students.sort(Comparator.comparing(student -> getLatestActionDate(student.getActions())))
```

Comment: students.sort(Comparator.comparing(student -> student.getLatestActionDate()));


this is the line I guess you are saying. But it still does not returns proper sorted list.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED IT:

For Parent class:

```
Collections.sort(students, (o1, o2) -> o2.getActions().get(0).getLastActionDate().compareTo(o1.getActions().get(0).getLastActionDate()));
```

Within child class Action, update the getter of getActions() as:

```
public List<Actions> getActions() {
        Collections.sort(actions, (o1, o2) -> o2.getLastActionDate().compareTo(o1.getLastActionDate()));
        return actions;
    }
```

So first we sort the inner objects that have the date object and then in parent, get the first **get(0)** object and sort parent against it.

I hope it helps someone in future.